# dependencies task not found with project.tasks.findByName

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

When I run `gradle tasks` it always lists `dependencies` task; But when I run the following code in my build.gradle it always return null : `project.tasks.findByName('dependencies')`

My requirement is to print the output of dependencies task into the log for reference as part of build.

I am on gradle version 1.11 (not authorized to upgrade)

Please help:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use a custom task of `org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.DependencyReportTask` type, and configured to print just sepecified configuration dependencies, as:

```
task printDeps(type: org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.DependencyReportTask) {
        configurations = project.buildscript.configurations + project.configurations
}
```

If you wish, you may exclude buildscript dependencies, if you don't need them.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Curious to know why it does not work for existing `dependencies` task.

Comment: @SundeepGupta I suppose, the reason is, that it's one of the help tasks and is not provided as the task within build script. Just like a `help` task